# How to run one mysql query servel times in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to `echo` an `img` every time `$i` increases, but it only `echo`s the last `$i`.

```
for($i=0; $i<=5;$i++)
    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT id, Make FROM sve WHERE id='".$i."'";

    $rezult=mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $red=mysqli_fetch_object($rezult);
    echo "<img src='brend/brend$red->id.png' class='imgbrend' strana='".$red->Make."'/>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's `IN` or `BETWEEN` keywords, rather than using a for loop and then iterate over the result set.

Your query becomes something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, Make FROM sve WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

Then you need a loop like so:

```
while ($red = mysqli_fetch_object($rezult)) {
    echo "<img src='brend/brend" . $red->id . ".png' class='imgbrend' strana='" . $red->Make . "'/>";
}
```

Full code:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id, Make FROM sve WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 5";

$rezult = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($red = mysqli_fetch_object($rezult)) {
    echo "<img src='brend/brend" . $red->id . ".png' class='imgbrend' strana='" . $red->Make . "'/>";
}
```